# Webpage with Sessions for authentication to Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql

I wrote a Webapp in PHP a few months ago.

After introduceing it to the Users I got the feddback that it would be usefull to also have it as a App.

What is the Best way of converting it to a Android Application?

The Authentication system is based on Sessions and everything is stored as Images and in a MySQL Server on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WebView which points to your website.

- Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
- iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

This WebView will work the same as a browser, just without browser specific things, such as a URL bar.

However, and i'm not sure on the use case of the app, this will mean users on the app will have to have an internet connection to use the mobile app. If this is a limitation for you, then you'll have to write a bespoke app which can handle offline access also.

Hope this helps :)